# How to get other app's pixel output in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible, using Unity 3D, to grab the pixel output of another, external app's window? So that one could say snapshot a game's pixels at a given time to analyze the color values etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible using built in Unity APIs.

It is possible using OS specific APIs. For Windows, the Desktop Duplication API is the ideal source of pixel data for other applications. Documentation can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api

You would need to create a DLL that uses this API and exposes the needed data to your Unity app.

An active project that makes this easier to consume within Unity is located at 
https://github.com/hecomi/uDesktopDuplication

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this! Do I understand correctly that using uDesktopDuplication, one would then not have to do the Create DLL step you describe?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen if you download the .unitypackage from the releases page, the author has gone through the trouble of building the DLL as well as providing a reasonable Unity C# interface.